# Dynamic columns for bag in apache pig

Tags: dynamic, apache-pig, dynamic-columns

I am new to Apache Pig. Is it possible to create the bag with dynamic columns?
    Following is the script for example.

```
 A = LOAD 'student' USING PigStorage() AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray, col3:chararray ....... );
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE col1, col3; OR
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE col2, col3, col4;
```

In short get the list of columns and create bag. Is it possible and how?
What I need here is way to get dynamic columns. so e.g. somebody define my script to run on params='col1,col2,col4' then my script should be able to parse this string and use it get the desired colums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest use MACRO or PARAMETER variable with script, for MACRO here is example

```
define dividend_analysis (daily, year, daily_symbol, daily_open, daily_close) 
returns analyzed { 
divs = load '/user/data/NYSE_dividends'as (exchange:chararray,     symbol:chararray, date:chararray, dividends:float); 
divisthisyear = filter divs by date matches '.*$year.*';
dailythisyear = filter $daily by date matches '.*$year.*'; 
jnd = join divisthisyear by symbol, dailythisyear by $daily_symbol;
$analyzed = foreach jnd generate $1 ,$daily_close - $daily_open; };

daily = load '/user/data/NYSE_daily'as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray,     date:chararray, open:float, high:float, low:float, close:float, volume:int,     adj_close:float); 
results = dividend_analysis(daily, '2009', 'symbol', 'open', 'close');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'student' using PigStorage(',');

by this relation A contains all columns which has student file.You can access these columns by using sequence number like $0,$1,$2
$0 --> First column
$1 --> Second column
$2 --> third column and so on
```

Comment: What I need here is way to get dynamic columns. so e.g. somebody define my script to run on params='col1,col2,col4' then my script should be able to parse this string and use it get the desired colums.